# How to play next file using Audio Queue Services

Tags: iphone, macos, audio, audioqueueservices

What is the right way to play next file using Audio Queue Services? When "play next" button is pressed should I first call AudioQueueStop and then AudioQueuePrime/AudioQueueStart or it is enough to just fill buffers with next file data?

The problem is that the latter gives me sound glitches on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a good solution?

You may have to reset the audio queue also, as the encoding might be different for each file.